# Regex unordered matches

Tags: java, regex

This feels like it should be an extremely simple thing to do with regex but I can't quite seem to figure it out.

I would like to write a regex which checks to see if a list of certain words appear in a document, in any order, along with any of a set of other words in any order.

In boolean logic the check would be: 
If allOfTheseWords are in this text and atLeastOneOfTheseWords are in this text, return true.

**Example**
I'm searching for (john and barbara) with (happy or sad). 
Order does not matter.

```
"Happy birthday john from barbara" => VALID
"Happy birthday john"              => INVALID
```

I simply cannot figure out how to get the and part to match in an orderless way, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you sure you are looking for a regex solution? if your app supposes to query a lot of time, and the text is relatively stable, you might prefer Information Retrieval techniques

Comment: Yeah it's starting to look like a regex is not necessarily what I want for this. Or at the very least multiple regexes should be used and I need to programatically ensure these matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really want to use a regex for this unless the text is very small, which from your description I doubt.

A simple solution would be to dump all the words into a HashSet, at which point checking to see if a word is present becomes a very quick and easy operation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with regex, I'd try **[positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**:

```
// searching for (john and barbara) with (happy or sad)
"^(?=.*\bjohn\b)(?=.*\bbarbara\b).*\b(happy|sad)\b"
```

The performance should be comparable to doing a full text search for each of the words in the *allOfTheseWords* group separately.

Comment: You probably want to avoid the greedy .* in the middle of the regex and use .*? instead in order to get the performance you claim.  .* in the middle will go the the end before backtracking.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a *single* regex, then it would be very large and very slow due to backtracking.  For your particular example of (John AND Barbara) AND (Happy or Sad), it would start like this:

```
\bJohn\b.*?\bBarbara\n.*?\bHappy\b|\bJohn\b.*?\bBarbara\n.*?\bSad\b|......
```

You'd ultimately need to put all combinations in the regex.  Something like:

```
JBH, JBS, JHB, JSB, HJB, SJB, BJH, BJS, BHJ, BSJ, HBJ, SBJ
```

Again backtracking would be prohibitive, as would the explosion in the number of cases.  Stay away from regexes here.

Answer (score 1):

With your example, this is a regex that may help you :

**Regex**

```
(?:happy|sad).*?john.*?barbara|
(?:happy|sad).*?barbara.*?john|
barbara.*?john.*?(?:happy|sad)|
john.*?barbara.*?(?:happy|sad)|
barbara.*?(?:happy|sad).*?john|
john.*?(?:happy|sad).*?barbara
```

**Output**

```
happy birthday john from barbara => Matched
Happy birthday john              => Not matched
```

As mentionned in other responses, a regex may not be well suited here.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do it with regexp, but it would be so complicated that it's better to use some different way (for example using a HashSet, as mentioned in the other answers).

One way to do it with regex would be to calculate all the permutations of the words which you are looking for, and then write a regex which mentions all those permutations. With 2 words there would be 2 permutations, as in `(.*foo.*bar.*)|(.*bar.*foo.*)` (plus word boundaries), with 3 words there would be 6 permutations, and quite soon the number of permutations would be larger than your input file.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is relatively constant, and you are planning on searching a lot, using [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) will ensure better peformance.

Using information retrieval techniques, you will first index all your documents/sentences, and then search for your words, in your example you would want to search for "+(+john +barbara) +(sad happy)" [or "(john AND barbarar) AND (sad OR HAPPY)" ]

this approach will consume some time when indexing, however, searching will be much faster then any regex/hashset approach (since you don't need to iterate over all documents...)